# Kusto query help for Time chart

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am writing a Kusto query to display ths status of build results in time chart. That is the first column will display the time in 5 mins difference and the remaining columns will have the count for the respective Build status like (sucess, failed, in progress)

Once I do all the filters, I am using the below query

´´´| summarize count= count() by Status ,bin(timestamp(), 1h)
| render timechart´´´

It says unknown function and I am not sure how to display a time chart. So for each status how do I get the count for every 5 mins. Thanks for any inputs.

[image: Refer picture for the sample chart]

Comment: The image is not attached...

Comment: The image is in the url // https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGqsn.png.  Is just a simple table I put as example to show how I need the time chart to be displayed

Comment: I answered. For future reference please provide examples as "datatable" it makes it much easier to answer...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the issue is that you are using the function notation when you are telling the "bin" function which column to use, instead of simply provide the name of the column. In other words, remove the parenthesis after the column name *timestamp* as follows:

```
T
| summarize count= count() by Status ,bin(timestamp, 1h) | render timechart
```

Comment: Thanks I am still working and will keep you posted on my results. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Still does not work. Below is the Query 

`Results (Datatable)
| where Branch == "ref/heads/m"| where RunType == "Partial"
| where Variation == "CI" or Variation == "PR"
| where Platform != "windows" | where Status == "Success" or Status == "Progress"
| extend duration = EndTime - QueueTime
| summarize count= count() by Status ,bin(timestamp, 1d)
| render timechart`

I am getting the error messgae - 'summarize' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'timestamp. I replaced timestamp with TimeGenerated still the same issue. nIt sure where I am making mistake. Thanks.

Comment: This means that the column does not exist in your input table. If you use EndTime or QueueTime it should work assuming that these columns exist.

Comment: perfect it works with the Queuetime and the render timechart displays the chart now. But  I have one final question pls. All the the status are displayed in the same column. is there a way I can show the count for diff staus in diff column  for the same Queue time

Comment: Do you mean the diff from the prior point of time? Can you send a sample of the data you have now and what you would like? Please use datatable() to provide the example

Comment: Below is the sample Datatable

`Branch": refs/heads/m,
"BuildDate": 2021-05-23T01:03:38.13Z,
"System": Buildr,
"EndTime": 2021-05-23T03:39:01.878037Z,
"Api": UWP,
"BuildId": 6482417,
"Platform": Linux,
"QueueTime": 2021-05-23T01:30:28.5509072Z,
"Renderer": ,
"RunType": Partialal,
"ID": 0130286678,
"Status": Success,
"Title": Buildr123,
"Trigger": Bott,
"Variation": CI`
for diff status I need the count in the seperate columns in the table.  firts column - Date, second - count of success, second - count of progress

Comment: Please provide the data using datatable() operator (see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datatableoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer).